# Assigning a DNS to AWS EC2 instance each time it is started

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have an EC2 instance that only runs periodically ( Lots of them ) and I want to assign the same DNS name to the same instance each time the instance starts up. I dont want to use Static IPs because the cost of these when instance is not running is almost as much as the instance itself costs.
Is it possible to do this without using static IPs?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what DNS service you are using. If you are using something like Route53 that lets you set a low TTL on the DNS records, and your DNS service has an API for updating records, then this should work fairly well. Simply add a script that will run when the EC2 instance boots, possibly via user-data, that will get the instance's latest IP and send an API request to your DNS service to update the IP address on the DNS record.

Comment: If using Route53 and an EC2 instance with the `awscli` installed, you can get the ip from  `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4` and use https://oliverhelm.me/sys-admin/updating-aws-dns-records-from-cli